# RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, wildfly, java-11

Hi when i am trying to open my applications' login page on browser , i am getting this exception.
P.S : open jdk zulu 11 and wildfly 24 for deployment.

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.getSession(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.demo.ear.rest.war//com.demoapp.demo.rest.resources.Myclass.init(Myclass.java:107)
```

Comment: There is a chance too that the request might not be available when `@PostConstruct` is invoked.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins how to handle this situation.

Comment: What is the situation you want to handle? What is your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the `@Context` is set on a per method basis.  More like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myMethod(String someString, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
```

In this way the `HttpServletRequest` is set on a method basis, not a class basis.  I don't think you want it at the class level as if the class has many methods those methods shouldn't share the same `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: This code was working well with jdk8 and wildlfy10. , but on jdk11 & wildfly24, it is throwing this exception.

Comment: I run this exact code on Wildfly 26 and Java 11 - can you share the exception?

Comment: Here is the complete exception  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72432085/weld-exception-wildfly-24-with-jdk-11

Comment: That looks like you're still doing the same thing.  Please create a reproducible example.

Comment: how can i modify the init() method to accept the parameter @Context HttpServletRequest request. this exception is there on the first line of the init method. is it correct way  init(@Context HttpServletRequest request) ? i doubt.

Comment: You cannot - as I indicated this goes on a method.  The HttpServletRequest only exists when a request comes in.  It does not exist during your `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is beans.xml in your Web-inf dir.  Then, remove and deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the quarkus-undertow dependency solved the problem for me.
I use quarkus 2.X